# Retaining information from multiple forms

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm putting together a page that displays data in a table with several columns.

Given the amount of information, I've limited the entries shown in one go, effectively creating pages.

I've also created a way to allow users to filter common entries using dropdowns over 3 of the columns (see the first section of code). I can apply any combination of the 3 filters (one, two or three filters in any combination) and it works fine.

The second section of code shows (one of) the links that goes back a page. This also works fine.

My issue is that while both sections of code work in isolation, they don't work together (i.e. I lose the filters if I try to change page, or end up being kicked back to page 1 if I filter).

I could probably get it all to work sending the requested page and 3 filters to the url and using GET to fetch the results, but that was starting to get very messy. I had a similar problem when trying to use SESSION; it got messy passing variables between POST and SESSION.

I'm fairly new to php so I expect that there's an elegant solution, either making a small change to get what I have to work, or perhaps something I've not thought of yet. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Code for the filters:

```
        echo "<form method=\"POST\">";          
        echo "<select name='courier_select' onchange='this.form.submit()'>";                        
        echo "<option value=\"\">--Select--</option>";

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($courierlist); ++$i) {
                if ($selcourier == $courierlist[$i]['review_courier']) {
                        echo '<option selected=\"selected\" value="'.$courierlist[$i]['review_courier'].'">'.$courierlist[$i]['review_courier'].'</option>';
                } else {
                        echo '<option value="'.$courierlist[$i]['review_courier'].'">'.$courierlist[$i]['review_courier'].'</option>';
                }
            }                           

        echo "</select>";

        echo "<select name='retailer_select' onchange='this.form.submit()'>";           
        echo "<option value=\"\">--Select--</option>";                  

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($retailerlist); ++$i) {
                if ($selretailer == $retailerlist[$i]['review_retailer']) {
                    echo '<option selected=\"selected\" value="'.$retailerlist[$i]['review_retailer'].'">'.$retailerlist[$i]['review_retailer'].'</option>';
                } else {
                    echo '<option value="'.$retailerlist[$i]['review_retailer'].'">'.$retailerlist[$i]['review_retailer'].'</option>';
                }
            }               

        echo "</select>";

        echo "<select name='rating_select' onchange='this.form.submit()'>";         
        echo "<option value=\"\">--Select--</option>";          

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($scorelist); ++$i) {
                if ($selscore == $scorelist[$i]['review_score']) {
                    echo '<option selected=\"selected\" value="'.$scorelist[$i]['review_score'].'">'.$scorelist[$i]['review_score'].'</option>';
                } else {
                    echo '<option value="'.$scorelist[$i]['review_score'].'">'.$scorelist[$i]['review_score'].'</option>';
                }
            }                               

        echo "</select>";                               
        echo "</form>";
```

Here is the code for (one of) the navigation buttons.

```
        echo "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"index.php?page=reviews\">";            
        echo    "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"page_no\" value=" . ($currentpage - 1) . ">";
        echo    "<button><</button>";
        echo "</form>";
```

Comment: you want to display data in a table depending on the selected item in the dropdown?

Comment: Yes, of which there are 3 dropdowns above 3 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sessions to save the values each filter has. This way, you do not need all that GET parameters to be passed every time the page changes.

```
// Start the session
session_start();

// Store all filter values in sessions 
// so they do not need to be passed every time a new page gets loaded
if(isset($_POST['courier_selec'])) {
    $_SESSION['filter_courier'] = $_POST['courier_selec'];
}

// Then use $_SESSION['filter_courier'] to generate the content of your pages:
if($_SESSION['filter_courier'] == "xy") { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a tidy way of doing this, going straight to session? eg. without using $_SESSION['var'] = $_POST['var'];

Comment: No, you need to do that. Don't forget to call session_start() at the beginning of your php script to make it work.

Comment: I've called session_start(). What's the best way to assign form data to the $_SESSION var?

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go tomorrow.

Comment: Nope, I can't get this to work properly. I'm not entirely sure why, but the SESSION code simply doesn't seem to come through in the right place. As I tried last time, it just gets messy.

Comment: Move the session stuff to the beginning of your file and show some code where the sessions are used please.

Comment: Got it working; I had some legacy code that was messing things up. Thanks for the help!